# Changing URL parameters in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url, parameters

I have a site with this URL: https://my_site.cz/index.php/prices/order/?button=1.
I want to change URL parameter button to 0.
I tried this javascript code:

```
var queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
queryParams.set("button", "0");
```

But it didn´t work. I tried other sugestions but the button variable remains unchanged.
How can I change the variable?
Thanks for any help
(I use wordpress and a Divi theme from Elegant themes.)

Answer (score 0):

The `queryParams` are currently a copy of the `window.location.search` values. You'll need to assign the `search` property of the `location` object to update the search params in the URL.

```
var queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
queryParams.set("button", "0");
window.location.search = queryParams;
```

When assigning an instance of `URLSearchParams` like here above, it will call the `toString()` method on the `URLSearchParams` object and convert the object to a string.